# Is there an extension or configuration to get VScode to use a single quartet of hotkeys to navigate between split-terminals and split-editor panes?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, text-editors, vscode-extensions

I come from a vi background, and I'm used to using something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H/J/K/L</kbd> to navigate around 'panes' in the editor interface, including both integrated terminals and text-editors.

I've got the following configuration, which gets me pretty close:

```json
// settings.json
"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
   "workbench.action.focusRightGroup",
   "workbench.action.focusLeftGroup",
   "workbench.action.focusAboveGroup",
   "workbench.action.focusBelowGroup"
],
```

```json
// keybindings.json
// ### Mimic some vi-bindings when in a terminal
{
   "key": "ctrl+w ctrl+l",
   "command": "workbench.action.focusRightGroup",
   "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
   "key": "ctrl+w ctrl+h",
   "command": "workbench.action.focusLeftGroup",
   "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
   "key": "ctrl+w ctrl+k",
   "command": "workbench.action.focusAboveGroup",
   "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
   "key": "ctrl+w ctrl+j",
   "command": "workbench.action.focusBelowGroup",
   "when": "terminalFocus"
},
// ...
```

This, for the most part, 'works' — I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H/J/K/L</kbd> to move left/down/up/right between pans, as well as using it to move "down" ("right", if you have your term in the sidebar) into the integrated-terminal drawer and then back "up" ("left") out of the integrated terminal drawer into the editors.

However, what I *cannot* do, is move "left"/"right" ("up"/"down") between *multiple*, split-pane integrated terminals — using those commands simply moves me back into the editor-pane.l The only way I currently have to switch between *terminals* is to use the built-in `workbench.action.terminal.focusNext` command (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> on macOS).

Is there some way for me to unify these? I *can* make it work in a single windowing configuration, jankily, by overriding the left/right **or** up/down keys when in `terminalFocus` setting, to invoke `terminal.focusNext` instead of `workbench.action.focusLeftGroup` or whatever … but that is fragile, and only works if the split-terminals *are* indeed organized left-to-right (which isn't true when the terminals are in the sidebar.)